# Measuring time taken by a function: clock_gettime

Tags: c, timing, clock

I am trying to measure how long a function takes.

I have a little issue: although I am trying to be precise, and use floating points, every time I print my code using `%lf` I get one of two answers: `1.000`... or `0.000`... This leads me to wonder if my code is correct:

```
#define BILLION  1000000000L;

// Calculate time taken by a request
struct timespec requestStart, requestEnd;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &requestStart);
function_call();
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &requestEnd);

// Calculate time it took
double accum = ( requestEnd.tv_sec - requestStart.tv_sec )
  + ( requestEnd.tv_nsec - requestStart.tv_nsec )
  / BILLION;
printf( "%lf\n", accum );
```

Most of this code has not been made by me. This example page had code illustrating the use of [`clock_gettime`](http://www.users.pjwstk.edu.pl/%7Ejms/qnx/help/watcom/clibref/qnx/clock_gettime.html):

Could anyone please let me know what is incorrect, or why I am only getting `int` values please?

Comment: No, no, no: don't give names to numbers. Use the function they serve instead: `#define CLOCK_PRECISION 1000000000L /* one billion */`

Comment: @pmg: Pedantry tangent: I'd argue that a name such as `CLOCK_PRECISION` would only be necessary if the units were not clear from the variable name.  In the case above, it's clear from the name `tv_nsec` that we're in nanoseconds.  So `NANOSECONDS_PER_SECOND` might be appropriate, but that's really not a great deal different to simply `BILLION`.

Comment: `CLOCK_REALTIME` is  affected  by  discontinuous  jumps in the system time. Consider using `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` — it is not affected by time adjustments with `adjtime()` and time jumps.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Dividing an integer by an integer yields an integer. Try this:

```
#define BILLION 1E9
```

And don't use a semicolon at the end of the line. `#define` is a preprocessor directive, not a statement, and including the semicolon resulted in `BILLION` being defined as `1000000000L;`, which would break if you tried to use it in most contexts. You got lucky because you used it at the very end of an expression and outside any parentheses.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. And thanks for letting me know about the semicolon, that is something I forgot. Thank you very much!

Comment: For sake of performance..
#define ONE_OVER_BILLION 1E-9
and use multiply.

Answer (score 9):

`( requestEnd.tv_nsec - requestStart.tv_nsec )` is of integer type, and is always less than `BILLION`, so the result of dividing one by the other in integer arithmetic will always be `0`.  You need to cast the result of the subtraction to e.g. `double` before doing the divide.

Answer (score 1):

Note that (requestEnd.tv_nsec - requestStart.tv_nsec) can be negative, in which case you need to subtract 1 second from the tv_sec difference and add one BILLION to the tv_nsec difference.

Comment: Downvote because answer is incorrect. In similar calculations, something like this may be necessary, but not here. If `requestEnd.tv_nsec - requestStart.tv_nsec` is negative and `BILLION` is the double `1E9`, then `(requestEnd.tv_nsec - requestStart.tv_nsec) / BILLION` will be a double between `-1.0` and `0.0`, and adding this number to `(requestEnd.tv_sec - requestStart.tv_sec)` will do the right thing, because the latter is implicitly converted to double. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion

Answer (score 1):

I know the question was posted long ago, but I still don't see the answer which would suggest you to "convert" elapsed time into nanoseconds (or milliseconds) and not into seconds as in your code sample.

The sample code fragment to illustrate the idea:

```
long long accum = ( requestEnd.tv_nsec - requestStart.tv_nsec )
 + ( requestEnd.tv_sec - requestStart.tv_sec ) * BILLION;
```

This way you can avoid floating point arithmetic, which may be heavy for some platforms...

Comment: Should be `/ BILLION`, not `* BILLION`

Comment: @FractalSpace , by multiplying we convert from seconds to nanoseconds.

Comment: Right. your units for `accum` are in ns, whereas OP's are in sec